# Trouble reading data with nested loop

Tags: c

So, this is part of my code looks like:

```c
int main(void) {
    char buf[64];

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
        int count = 1;
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &count) != 1) {
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL) {
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("%s", buf);
            other_function(buf); //to analyze the second kinds of data in the code
        }
        other_function2();
        printf("%d\n", other_function2);
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL && strcmp(buf, "0\n") == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have a **.txt** file that has two kinds of information, which looks like below, I just want to explain that two kinds of information look totally different.
And I used the code to distinguish these two data (the first kind kind only contained one integer)

```
5
A 08:15 C 12:30 2500
C 14:05 A 17:30 2500
C 15:30 A 18:00 3000
C 14:30 B 17:50 3000
B 08:30 C 13:35 3000
4
A 08:15 C 12:30 2500
C 14:04 A 17:30 2500
C 14:30 B 17:50 3000`
...

A 14:30 C 17:50 3000

0
```

I want the code end when it meets the last line `0`
but it always output the `0` and output other things after that, which I didn't know where the data is from...

And if I change `int count = 1` ; to `int count = 0`, the program will stop after meets the second single integer. (like in this sample input, which will be '7')

I posted the questions earlier before, but I think I did not explain it very well, so I deleted it.

If there are still something I did not explain very well, please tell me.

Comment: @tadman part of I will edit my post for the input.
and the sscanf() function is used to extract the integer from the string buf and store it in the variable count

Comment: Changing `count` from 1 to 0 doesn't do anything as you read it via `scanf` anyway. Is that correct that you have an empty line between all lines with text? That will not match your calls to `fgets`.

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i < count; i++)` would only iterate twice when `count = 3`, as it would be for the first case of your text file. That likely isn't what you want. `printf("%d\n", other_function2);` is also likely not what you want, as this is printing the address of the function as a decimal.

Comment: @Gerhardh There is no empty line in the input file.

Comment: Well, there is one left... but that is probably an error. Your code is wrong as it reads the line holding the integer for `count` at the end of the loop and another line in the loop condition. You mustn't try to read that line twice.

Comment: `int i = 1` should be `int i = 0`. When `count` is 5, your code will only read 4 more lines instead of 5.

Comment: @h0r53 sorry that I did not explain well in my question.
The only output I want is what `printf("%d\n", other_function2);` got,
 `printf( "%d\n", count);`, and `printf( "%s", buf);` are for checking if the data have been written in correctly.

Comment: My code can either work perfectly and stopped after the set or continued after still meet the number 0.

Comment: For more context please see the previous closed question [read in data and output nothing with a logical problem(myself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76787138/read-in-data-and-output-nothing-with-a-logical-problemmyself). For some reason OP has changed the loop I suggested there. All they needed to do is add `if(count == 0) break;` to pick up the end marker.

Answer (score 3):

You try to consume the lines holding integers twice.

You need to read only once. But as you already read the `count`, you can simply use that instead of comparing with `"0\n"`.

Also as others already mentioned in comments, your inner loop doesn't read enough lines.

Try this (with extra test output and stubs for missing functions)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void other_function(char *buf)
{
  // strip trailing \name
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
  printf("Called other_function with buf=\"%s\"\n", buf);
}

void other_function2(void)
{
  printf("Called other_function2\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    char buf[64];

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        int count = 1;
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &count) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read number. Wrong input format\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Parsed number of following lines to read: %d\n", count);

        if (count == 0)   // <<=== check for sentinel entry `0` here.
        {
            printf("Sentinel '0' detected. Done.\n");
            break;
        }

        printf( "%d\n", count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)  // <<=== fix start counter to 0
        {
            if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read another line\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("%s", buf);
            other_function(buf); //to analyze the second kinds of data in the code
        }
        other_function2();
        // printf("%d\n", other_function2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test using this input file test.txt:

```
5
A 08:15 C 12:30 2500
C 14:05 A 17:30 2500
C 15:30 A 18:00 3000
C 14:30 B 17:50 3000
B 08:30 C 13:35 3000
4
A 08:15 C 12:30 2500
C 14:04 A 17:30 2500
C 14:30 B 17:50 3000`
A 14:30 C 17:50 3000
0
```

```
$ ./test < test.txt
Parsed number of following lines to read: 5
5
A 08:15 C 12:30 2500
Called other_function with buf="A 08:15 C 12:30 2500"
C 14:05 A 17:30 2500
Called other_function with buf="C 14:05 A 17:30 2500"
C 15:30 A 18:00 3000
Called other_function with buf="C 15:30 A 18:00 3000"
C 14:30 B 17:50 3000
Called other_function with buf="C 14:30 B 17:50 3000"
B 08:30 C 13:35 3000
Called other_function with buf="B 08:30 C 13:35 3000"
Called other_function2
Parsed number of following lines to read: 4
4
A 08:15 C 12:30 2500
Called other_function with buf="A 08:15 C 12:30 2500"
C 14:04 A 17:30 2500
Called other_function with buf="C 14:04 A 17:30 2500"
C 14:30 B 17:50 3000`
Called other_function with buf="C 14:30 B 17:50 3000`"
A 14:30 C 17:50 3000
Called other_function with buf="A 14:30 C 17:50 3000"
Called other_function2
Parsed number of following lines to read: 0
Sentinel '0' detected. Done.
```

Comment: Untested? Why is it?

Comment: @0___________ because I had no compiler at hand when I wrote that answer and wouldn't get one for some hours. What other possible reasons com to your mind?